# The total shows the price with .999995 at end

Tags: jquery, calculator

I have an error on this script. The calculation system works but it has an error:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#total").val("55.95");
    $("#amount").val("512MB");
    $("#amount1").val("512MB");
    $("#amountb").val("10GB");
    $("#amount2").val("10GB");

    $( function() {
        var ram = {

            0: "512MB",
            1: "1GB",
            2: "2GB",
            3: "4GB",
            4: "8GB",
            5: "16GB",
            6: "32GB",

        };
        var pram = {

            0: "49.95",
            1: "89.95",
            2: "149.95",
            3: "32",
            4: "64",
            5: "128",
            6: "256",

        }
        var hdd = {

            0: "10GB",
            1: "15GB",
            2: "20GB",
            3: "25GB",
            4: "30GB",
            5: "35GB",

        };
        var phdd = {

            0: "49.95",
            1: "99.95",
            2: "100.95",
            3: "49.14",
            4: "28",
            5: "40",
        }
        $("#slider").slider({

            value: "0",
            min: 0,
            max: 6,
            step: 0,
            slide: function(event, ui) {

                $("#price").val(pram[ui.value]);
                $("#amount").val(ram[ui.value]);
                $("#amount1").val(ram[ui.value]);
                var aaa = $("#price").val();
                var bbb = $("#priceb").val();
                $("#total").val(+aaa + +bbb);
            }
        });

        $("#sliderb").slider({
            value: "0",
            min: 0,
            max: 5,
            step: 1,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $("#priceb").val(phdd[ui.value]);
                $("#amountb").val(hdd[ui.value]);
                $("#amount2").val(hdd[ui.value]);
                var aaa = $("#price").val();
                var bbb = $("#priceb").val();
                $("#total").val(+aaa + +bbb);
            }
        });

        $("#price").val('$' + $("#slider").slider("value"));
        $("#priceb").val('$' + $("#slider").slider("value"));


        $("#price").val("4");
        $("#priceb").val("3");


    }
    );
});
```

If I calcultate 49.95 + 149.95 the result is 199.89999995, and the result is 199.9
I don't know what to do. Please help me

Comment: what if you try rounding to 2 decimal places?

Comment: Don't use floating point values for monetary data. Keep your prices in cents and format the numbers accordingly for the presentation. Floats always have a rounding error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken.

Comment: and how do I change this ?

Comment: `49.95` becomes `4995`. I.e. multiply the price by 100.

Comment: if i change it to 4995 it has no error. But I need it with point

Comment: JavaScript has the `/` operator for division. You just divide by 100. Basic math ;)

Comment: `+aaa + +bbb` is it good way to parse?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use floating point values for monetary data. Keep your prices in cents and format the numbers accordingly for the presentation. [Floats always have a rounding error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken).

If you work with cents, all you have to do is divide by `100` if you want to show the values in dollars (or any other currency):

```
var total = 4495 + 14995;
var display = total / 100;
$("#total").val(display);
```

Comment: but the total is not a value is like "$("#total").val("56.95");"

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: i don't have a var total. The total looks like this "$("#total").val("56.95");"

Comment: It's just an **example**. You have to adjust your code to use cents, that's the whole point. I provided a general solution, now you have to apply it to your code.

Answer (score 0):

your function which returns the formatted currency should round to 2.d.p, e.g.

```
var symbol="&#36; ";
var p1 = 49.95;
var p2 = 149.95;
var sum = p1+p2;
return symbol+sum.toFixed(2); //just return the sum to 2 decimal places
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want `199.89999995` as `199.9`, try:

```
var x = 49.95 + 149.95;    

Math.ceil(x *10) / 10;   // 199.9
```

If it's the rounding error, then nothing can be done about it other than what Felix King suggested.